# JqPlot pie chart jqplot-event-canvas position top left

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, jqplot, pie-chart

I've just started using JqPlot and want to display a small chart

However there is always a small margin at the top and to the left.

[image: Padding on top and left]

Looking at the css produced the jqplot-event-canvas is given absolute position with top and left set at 10px.

Is there a simple way to solve this so that the pie is positioned without the extra spacing?

I've tried to set the padding to 0 in the grid and pie rendererOptions.
Also set show:false on the axes, title, ledgend ..., 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting the `gridPadding` like this:

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot('pie1', [data], {
    gridPadding: {top:0, bottom:0, left:0, right:0},
....
```

Because by default, each plot has the following grid padding:

```
{top:10, right:10, bottom:23, left:10};
```

I think this might explain the issue you are seeing.

Comment: This is really awesome :)